# How to update the controller and the view after adding a field table to the db in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added a new field table to the db file. I've run the migration. Everything is ok. 
How can I update the webpage with a new form related to the new field? the migration doesn't
add the field automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the field to the view template under app/views/[model_name]s/.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Should I need to modify also the controller file?